# Excel help Needed

Tags: excel-formula

I need help on comparing two dates and giving a value. I am currently using =IF(AND(N2>=$B2,N2<=$C2),"1H","1E") where N2(a date) has to be greater that equal to and less than equal to dates B2 and C2.

Please help!

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Its not populating the codes 1E and 1H correctly.

Comment: Can you do F2, copy the contents and post here along with the cell reference (B2, C2 etc) for the set of cells that are resulting in wrong results?

Comment: @MikeC =IF(AND(J2>=$H2,J2<=$I2),"1E","1H") gives me code 1H for 1-1-2015(J2) for 7-29-2013(H2) and 12-31-2015(I2)

Comment: @MikeC I can email you the sheet if you like

Comment: What is the short date format on your computer? It is under Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats tab. Is it MM-DD-YYYY as you're using or is it MM/DD/YYYY. While you're at it, do check the Format value at the top of tab. What is it?

Comment: @MikeC yes its incorrect. Its not allowing me to change it too mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @MikeC actually it does not have the option

Comment: Your question was down voted by 2 people because there is not enough information to go on. I upvoted it because I know new users of this site are not aware of what is expected from them. But you're still not giving me enough to go on. Please answer the specific questions I asked in my previous comments if you want me to go on trying to help you.

Comment: @MikeC  Thanks a lot :-) It was the system issue- the date format thing. The formula did work.Have a nice weekend friend!

Comment: It is customary to upvote an answer (using the up arrow) and accept it (using the check mark next to it) if it helps you with your question. I'm posting my questions that led to your solving it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reproducing the comment that led to finding the problem and solving it.

What is the short date format on your computer? It is under Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats tab. Is it MM-DD-YYYY as you're using or is it MM/DD/YYYY. While you're at it, do check the Format value at the top of tab. What is it?